# How do I calculate total resistance?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance

As far as I understand, two resistors are connected in parallel if the node at both ends of both resistors are the same. And in series if only one node is the same.

But what if between two resistors there is/are some component(s) like Voltage Source, Current Source, Ammeter, etc?

For example in this circuit:
[image: circuit]

The R2 is parallel to the R3. $$=> R_{23} = R_{2} || R_{3}$$

But after that, the R1 is parallel or in series to R23? And why?

And if there was no current source, would it change the relationship between R1 and R23?

Thanks.

Comment: In this case is neither in parallel and neither in series.  Rtotal = R1||(E/J)

Comment: Can you explain how did you come up to that conclusion that it's neither in parallel nor in series? Would be helpful to me. :)

Comment: J is infinite impedance in series with R23 so the equivalent or right hand half loop Z=E/J  while E is a 0 Ohm source on the left

Comment: They picked annoyingly non-neutral names for their current sources- E which is often used for voltage and J which is often used for current *density*.

Answer (score 0):

The current source produces a constant currency applied over a constant resistance R23. Sounds like it's actually a voltage source at that point,  right? The voltage at the top of R23 must be J * R23 because of Ohms law.